# How can I use Chrome through Tor on OS X?

Tags: chrome, mac

How do I properly set up Chrome on my Mac OS X machine to run all traffic through the Tor network when the Tor network is running?

- **Chrome Version**: 29.0.1547.76
- **Mac OS X Version**: 10.8.5
- **Tor**: 0.2.3.25

Comment: Wasn't there a meta discussion a while back where we decided that questions about configuring specific software to use Tor were on topic? Maybe I'm imagining it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is [recommended against by The Tor Project](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherBrowser). And I quote their FAQ:

> In short, using any browser besides Tor Browser with Tor is a really bad idea.
>
> Our efforts to work with the Chrome team to [add missing APIs](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/google-chrome-incognito-mode-tor-and-fingerprinting) were unsuccessful, unfortunately. Currently, it is impossible to use other browsers and get the same level of protections as when using the Tor Browser.

In theory, you could route all traffic over Tor using a (custom) [Transparent Proxy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy), such as [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org) or [Qubes OS TorVM](http://qubes-os.org/trac/wiki/UserDoc/TorVM), this would hide your IP, but would still be only pseudonymous rather than anonymous, because Tor Browser is currently the only browser keeping care of the protocol level leaks.

At the moment, it won't work without some kind of Transparent Proxy, due to [proxy bypass bugs](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/ImportantGoogleChromeBugs#ProxyBypassBugs) in Chrome. (Feel free to remove this, should the proxy bypass bugs be fixed some day.)

Comment: Update: *Our **efforts to work with** the **Chrome** team to add missing APIs **were unsuccessful**, unfortunately. Currently, it is impossible to use other browsers and get the same level of protections as when using the Tor Browser.*