# How to make the Tor-Launcher extension for Chrome?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Is it possible to make the Tor-Launcher for Chrome?If it is possible，how I should do?

Comment: **[once again](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/why-not-make-a-new-browser-based-on-chromium):** please read the [FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherBrowser) or [the related question on this site](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-can-i-use-chrome-through-tor-on-os-x)!