# How can I enable Tor on Chrome

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am using Ubuntu. Downloaded the latest version of Tor from [here](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en). But when I execute `./start-tor-browser` from terminal it starts in firefox. How can I enable it in Chrome?

Also how can I launch Tor without using terminal?

Comment: Short answer: if you want to use Tor for reasons of anonymity, you can't use Chrome. (See the related threads on this site.) For your second question: there should be a `.desktop` file in the same directory as the start script you've run.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks thanks =), Yes there is a `.desktop` file in the folder, what should be my next step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am using Ubuntu. Downloaded the latest version of tor from here. But
>   when I execute ./start-tor-browser from terminal it starts in firefox.

When you run the `start-tor-browser` script, you're starting the Tor Browser application. The Tor Browser is modified version of Firefox, which has been changed to make it safe from the perspective of anonymity. It's *not* the Firefox application you might have already had on your computer. (i.e. You're not starting "Tor" as a service inside your good old Firefox that you installed x years ago.)

> How can I enable it in chrome?

If you're using Tor because you want to surf the Internet anonymously, you can't really use Chrome. Have a read of [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-can-i-use-chrome-through-tor-on-os-x/55#55) thread to understand why not.

> Also how can I launch tor without using terminal?

In Tor's `Browser` folder there's a `.desktop` file. Using the terminal, copy it as follows:

`cp tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`

You should now be able to find a Tor Browser icon in Ubuntu's menu bar. (Search "Tor" and it should appear.)