# How to torify a web browser?

Tags: ubuntu, browsers

I have successfully torified a program in terminal under Ubuntu, following https://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-anonymize-the-programs-from-your-terminal-with-torify:

> In this example we’ll keep all the standard configuration but 2
>   things, in the file /etc/tor/torrc you should uncomment the directive:
>
> ```
> ControlPort 9051
> ```
>
> And set
>
> ```
> CookieAuthentication 0
> ```
>
> With these 2 options we set the port on which Tor will listen for
>   local connections from Tor controller applications, and we tell to Tor
>   that we don’t need an authentication, so any program can control Tor
>   (don’t do this on a shared computer or server)

Now I want to test if torify works for a web browser.
`torify firefox` invokes firefox which shows my real external ip through ip lookup websites. `torify google-chrome` doesn't invoke chrome browser at all.

Why do they not work? How can I make them work? Thanks.

Comment: What is your aim in trying to Torify a browser? To then use that browser on the Tor network for privacy/anonymity reasons, or something else?

Comment: "use that browser on the Tor network for privacy/anonymity reasons"

Comment: Have you looked into using the Tor Browser?

Comment: I thought of it. but is it possible to use torify with firefox or chrome?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really possible, and [officially advised against](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherBrowser).

The whole reason the Tor Browser was created was because of the difficulties in trying to make other browsers "safe".

Have a look at the [Tor Browser Design Document](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/), specifically the section on [Design Requirements and Philosophy](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#DesignRequirements) to understand the problems that have to be overcome when creating a Tor-compliant browser.

I believe there are further specific reasons as to why Chrome is a particularly bad candidate for Torification, as discussed in an official [blog post](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/google-chrome-incognito-mode-tor-and-fingerprinting), and in [previous answers](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-can-i-use-chrome-through-tor-on-os-x/55#55).

Bottom line is: use the [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en).